# Procedimiento almacenado c sharp

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, stored-procedure

En relación a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272879/llamar-a-un-procedimiento-almacenado-sqlquery-desde-c).
Tengo tres tablas: `REGISTRO_C` , `HISTORICO_REGISTRO` y `REGISTRO_GENERAL`

Desde mi aplicación web inserto datos en `REGISTRO_C`

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado para hacer la carga masiva a partir de la primera tabla en las tablas `HISTORICO_REGISTRO` y `REGISTRO_GENERAL`.

En `HISTORICO_REGISTRO` se guardarán los datos de `REGISTRO_C` (a modo de backup) que hay en bbdd antes de realizar el `insert`.

En `REGISTRO_GENERAL` se actualizarán los datos, puesto que `REGISTRO_C` contiene cambios en algunas celdas de `REGISTRO_GENERAL`.

Necesito saber cómo llamar a estos procedimientos con c sharp.

Gracias y perdonen mi explicación. Me estoy iniciando en esto :)

Comment: se dice procedimiento almacenado, no de almacenado.

Answer (score 2):

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es llamar por su nombre al procedimiento y darle los parámetros que necesites. Yo tengo un motor genérico así:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado que devuelve datos.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Procedimiento">Nombre del procedimiento a ejecutar.</param>
/// <param name="Datos">Parámetros del procedimiento.</param>
/// <returns>DataSet con la información devuelta por el procedimiento almacenado.</returns>
public DataSet ExecuteSP(string procedimiento, params SqlParameter[] datos)
{
    try
    {
        // Crea la conexión con SQL Server
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Cadena de conexión"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(procedimiento, con))
            {
                // Especifica que será un procedimiento almacenado.
                cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // Agrega los parámetros necesarios
                foreach (param p in datos)
                {
                    cmnd.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
                con.Open();
                // AQUÍ se ejecuta el procedimiento
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmnd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    con.Close();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        e.Log();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Este método puede ser llamado así (suponiendo una clase que se llame "DBLink"):

```
DBLink link = new DBLink();
link.ExecuteSP("sp_REGISTRO_DOC_Actualizar", new SqlParameter("@LOTE_CARGA", /* Tu valor */));
```

Incluso le puedes agregar los parámetros que necesites:

```
link.ExecuteSP("sp_REGISTRO_DOC_Actualizar",
    new SqlParameter("@LOTE_CARGA", /* Tu valor 1 */),
    new SqlParameter("@Param2", /* Tu valor */),
    new SqlParameter("@Param3", /* Tu valor */),
    new SqlParameter("@Param4", /* Tu valor */));
```

Es un ejemplo, en realidad hay muchas maneras de hacerlo y por lo menos otra manera de obtener información DESDE un procedimiento almacenado, pero este código es muy parecido al que yo utilizo en mis proyectos y me ha traído muy buenos resultados.

**Postdata**: [No nombres tus procedimientos almacenados con el prefijo `sp_`](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=es&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tech-recipes.com%2Frx%2F60700%2Fperformance-tip-avoid-using-sp_-prefix-stored-procedures%2F) para evitar problemas y mejorar el rendimiento.

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien lo que quieres es llamar a varias procedimientos almacenados de una forma correcta y al estar relacionados dentro de una transacción.

Te pongo código a modo de ejemplo:

```
public void LanzarConTrasaccion()
{
    // Variables locales
    string cadenaConex = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db1;Integrated Security=True";

    // Se utiliza la instrucción using para asegurarnos la desctrucción de los objetos y liberar recursos
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConex))
    {
        try
        {
            // Se abre la conexión
            con.Open();

            // Se prepara una transacción por si acaso falla la ejecución haya una vuelta atrás
            using (var trans = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        // Al comando se le asigna una conexión y la transacción
                        com.Connection = con;
                        com.Transaction = trans;

                        // Se le indica el tipo de comando y el nombre
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.CommandText = "CrearRegistro";

                        // Se añaden los parámetros de entrada
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", "Fulano");
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantidad", 69);

                        // Se ejecuta el procedimiento y se comprueba la salida
                        var registrosAfectados = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        // Al comando se le asigna una conexión y la transacción
                        com.Connection = con;
                        com.Transaction = trans;

                        // Se le indica el tipo de comando y el nombre
                        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        com.CommandText = "ActualizarRegistro";

                        // Se añaden los parámetros de entrada
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", DateTime.Now);

                        // Se ejecuta el procedimiento y se comprueba la salida
                        var registrosAfectados = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    trans.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Nos aseguramos de cerrar la conexión en caso de error
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver antes empezar con la transacción abro la conexión, controlo las posibles excepciones con `try-catch-finally` para evitar dejar la conexión abierta y para que haga `Rollback` en caso de error. En este caso llamo a dos procedimientos almacenados `CrearRegistro` y `ActualizarRegistro`, para confirmar finalmente la transacción si todo ha ido bien y en el `finally` cerrar la conexión.

Cualquier duda nos comentas. Te dejo el código completo en [GitHub](https://github.com/RublenX/Aprendiendo/blob/master/StackoverflowRespuestas/WinFrmReferenciaExterna/AccesoDatos.cs).

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas

```
var variableResultado = _objdbConexion.Database.SqlQuery<Dto>
                                    ("Nombredel_SP @variable={0}, @variable={1}, @variable={2}, @variable={3}",Dato, Dato, Dato,Dato).FirstOrDefault<Dto>();
```

O puedes hacerlo de esta forma si lo estas llamando dentro de tu modelo

```
 List<Dto_sp> _variable = new List<Dto_sp>();              
                    _variable = _objdbConexion.Nombredel_SP (Dato,dato, Dato,dato).ToList();
```