# Llamar a un procedimiento almacenado SQLQuery desde C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, stored-procedure

Mi finalidad es llamar al procedimiento almacenado y que este se ejecute.
He encontrado este código y lo he adaptado a mis necesidades pero me sale el error:  "No se puede implementar el método o la operación". 
Antes de este error me salía "No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConectionString" y la he inicializado. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
private bool BackupBBDD()
{
    bool backup = false;
    SqlConnection conexion = null;
    SqlTransaction transaccion = null;
    try
    {
        conexion = new SqlConnection();
        ABCEntities cadenaConexion = new ABCEntities();

        conexion.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion;

        conexion.Open();

        transaccion = conexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        SqlCommand commando = new SqlCommand("sp_REGISTRO_DOC_Actualizar", conexion, transaccion);
        commando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        commando.Parameters.Clear();

        commando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOTE_CARGA", SqlDbType.Int);

        commando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) //PETA "No se puede implementar el método o la operación"
    {
        return backup;  
    }
    finally
    {
        if (backup is true)
        {
            transaccion.Commit();
            conexion.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            conexion.Close();
            backup = false;
        }
    }
    return backup;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Leandro te ha indicado bien dónde estás errando, pero creo que te falta un ejemplo que te sirva de base.

Este te puede veir muy bien ya que abarca casi todas las posibilidades. Usa buenas prácticas como la instrucción using, además de indicar cómo declarar parámetros de entrada también indica cómo declarar y UTILIZAR los parámetros de salida. El procedimiento almacenado podría ser algo como esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CantidadesMayoresPorUsuario 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @cantidadMayorQue decimal = 0, 
    @idUsuario int,
    @codError int = 0 OUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @codError = 100;

    IF @cantidadMayorQue < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @codError = -100;
        RETURN -1;
    END
    ELSE
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        SELECT * FROM TablaPoC1 WHERE Cantidad > @cantidadMayorQue AND (@idUsuario IS NULL OR Id = @idUsuario)
    RETURN 1;
END
GO
```

Y el código en C# este otro:

```
public void LanzarExecuteReader()
{
    // Variables locales
    string cadenaConex = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db1;Integrated Security=True";
    List<TablaPoc1> lista = new List<TablaPoc1>();
    int codError = 0;
    int returnValue = 0;

    // Se utiliza la instrucción using para asegurarnos la desctrucción de los objetos y liberar recursos
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConex))
    {
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                // Al comando se le asigna una conexión
                com.Connection = con;

                // Se le indica el tipo de comando y el nombre
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.CommandText = "CantidadesMayoresPorUsuario";

                // Se añaden los parámetros de entrada
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", DBNull.Value);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidadMayorQue", 5);

                // Se añaden los parámetros de salida y se crean variables para facilitar su recuperacion
                SqlParameter paramOutCodError = com.Parameters.Add("@codError", SqlDbType.Int, int.MaxValue);
                paramOutCodError.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlParameter paramReturned = com.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.Int, int.MaxValue);
                paramReturned.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                // Se abre la conexión
                con.Open();

                // Se recupera el lector de datos al utilizar ExecuteReader
                SqlDataReader lector = com.ExecuteReader();

                // Mientras no terminer de leer filas ejecuta recupera la información obtenida
                while (lector.Read())
                {
                    // Creamos un objeto con los parámetros obtenidos de la consulta
                    TablaPoc1 fila = new TablaPoc1
                    {
                        Id = lector["Id"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)lector["Id"] : 0,
                        Nombre = lector["Nombre"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)lector["Nombre"] : string.Empty,
                        Fecha = lector["Fecha"] != DBNull.Value ? (DateTime)lector["Fecha"] : DateTime.MinValue,
                        Cantidad = lector["Cantidad"] != DBNull.Value ? (decimal)lector["Cantidad"] : 0
                    };

                    // Añadimos la fila al listado
                    lista.Add(fila);
                }

                // Se cierrra el lector de datos para poder recuperar los parámetros de salida
                lector.Close();

                // Se recuperan los parámetros de salida
                codError = (paramOutCodError.Value != null && paramOutCodError.Value != DBNull.Value) ? (int)paramOutCodError.Value : 0;
                returnValue = (paramOutCodError.Value != null && paramReturned.Value != DBNull.Value) ? (int)paramReturned.Value : 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Nos aseguramos de cerrar la conexión en caso de error
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    // Variable para poner un punto de parada de depuración y ver los resultados
    int parada = lista.Count;
}
```

El código está comentado pero si necesitas alguna explicación coméntalo en la respuesta y lo vamos viendo.

Debes tener en cuenta que dependiendo del tipo de ejecución SQL debes llamar a un método u otro del comando, me explico:

- **ExecuteReader**: sirve para obtener un listado de resultados.
- **ExecuteNonQuery**: sirve para realizar modificaciones en base de datos, devolviendo el número de filas afectadas.
- **ExecuteScalar**: devuelve la primera fila de la primera columna en una consulta.

Saludos y espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Observo que no le pasas un valor al parametro que asignas al command, aqui

```
commando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOTE_CARGA", SqlDbType.Int);
```

defines el nombre del parametro y el tipo de datos, pero que valor tomara es lo que falta.

Hay varias formas de lograrlo, podrias usar

```
private bool BackupBBDD(int loteCarga)
{
     //resto codigo

    commando.Parameters.Add("@LOTE_CARGA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = loteCarga;

    //resto codigo
}
```

o simplemente usar

```
private bool BackupBBDD(int loteCarga)
{
     //resto codigo

    commando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOTE_CARGA", loteCarga);

    //resto codigo
}
```

ya que al asignar un tipo `int` resuelve el tipo de dato automatiamente